# How to map img src with the results of an async function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the map function to render images with Material UI, but I have to fetch the url from the API before displaying them, that is what getFoto() is doing, but It displays nothing

```js
return(
    <div className={classes.root}>
            
        <GridList cellHeight={180} className={classes.gridList}>
          <GridListTile key="Subheader" cols={2} style={{ height: 'auto' }}>
            
          </GridListTile>
          {data && data.map((tile) => (            

            <GridListTile key={tile.propertyId} >  
                                                         
            <Link to={`/AreasRegistradas/${tile.propertyId}`}>
              <img  src={(async () => {                         // <======Here is the problem
                  await getFoto(tile.propertyId)
              })()}
                    
                    alt={tile.propertyName} 
                    className={"MuiGridListTile-tile"}
              />
            </Link>
            
              
              <GridListTileBar
                title={tile.propertyName}
                subtitle={<span> {tile.address}</span>}
                actionIcon={
                  <div>
                    <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>console.log("edit")}>
                      <EditIcon />
                    </IconButton>                  
                    <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>console.log("delete")}>
                      <DeleteForeverIcon />
                    </IconButton>                  
                  </div>
                }
              />
            </GridListTile>
          ))
        }
        </GridList>

        

    </div>
  )
```

However, if I do console.log (await getFoto(tile.propertyId)) it returns the correct urls that I need

```js
//.....
<img  src={(async () => {
                console.log(await getFoto(tile.propertyId))  //this returns the values that I need in the console            
          })()}
//.....
```

What can be the problem here? I'm new in this async functions world please help.
Thanks!

Im using:

-"react": "^16.13.1"

Comment: You can do it in alternate method like: 
getFoto().then(src=> <img src={src}/>)

Comment: No, please don't run async functions inside render.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `src={await getFoto(...)}` you are setting the `src` attribute (a string obviously) to a Promise, which clearly won't work. Rather, somewhere in your component code, such as the `componentDidMount` event, you should fetch the image and set the result to some state variable which then becomes the src:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const photo = await getFoto(tile.propertyId);
  this.setState({photo});
}
...
render() {
  ...
  <img src={state.photo} />
```

But note, this is assuming that what is returned is photo URL. If it's the image itself, you'll need to use base64. Something like `src={`data:image/png;base64,${state.photo}`}`. It also assumes `title` is in scope in the `componentDidMount` method. If it isn't, you'll need to use the correct reference (e.g. `this.tile`, `this.props.tile`?).

Comment: Great idea! But I need the propertyId to call the getFoto() function, and I access that inside my map function ( tile => tile.propertyid). If i call the getFoto inside the componentDidMount at the begginning how can I set this properyId for each property inside my map function?

Comment: I see. In that case, each tile should be its own component. You can use a function component with useEffect and useState (see eg https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data), or a class component with its own componentDidMount and setState.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [see sharper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1284760/see-sharper) for the advice!!! Here's what I did:
First I created a new component called < Tile /> , added it inside my original map function and passed the item as props:

```js
//...
          {data && data.map((tile) => (            
              <div key={tile.propertyId}> 
                <Tile tile={tile} />
              </div>
            ))
          }
//...
```

Then inside my new < Tile /> component I added what I had originally inside my map function plus the async function inside a useEffect hook and store the fetched url in a useState hook:

```js
function Tile(props){
  const {tile} = props  
  const [imgSrc, setImgSrc] = useState(''); // here is the hook for the url
   
  useEffect(() => {
    const getFoto = async (propId) =>{          
      try{
        const url = `....url/${propId}/images`
        const response = await fetch(url, {
          //authorization stuff
          }
        });

        const responseData = await response.json()       
        setImgSrc(responseData.items[0].imageUrl)  //setting the fetched url in a hook
      }catch(error){
      console.log(error)
      } 
      }

    getFoto(tile.propertyId);
  }, []);


    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      root: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      },
      gridList: {
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
      },
      icon: {
        color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)',
      },
    }));
    const classes = useStyles();
   

  return(
    <GridListTile className={"MuiGridListTile-tile"}>  
                                               
      <Link to={`/AreasRegistradas/${tile.propertyId}`}>

        <img  src={imgSrc}                    
              alt={tile.propertyName} 
              className={"MuiGridListTile-tile"}
        />
      </Link>

        
        <GridListTileBar
          title={tile.propertyName}
          subtitle={<span> {tile.address}</span>}
          actionIcon={
            <div>
              <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>console.log("edit")}>
                <EditIcon />
              </IconButton>                  
              <IconButton aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`} className={classes.icon} onClick={()=>console.log("delete")}>
                <DeleteForeverIcon />
              </IconButton>                  
            </div>
          }
        />
    </GridListTile>
  )

}
```

Thanks again!